# Creating new resources with nested form with polymorphic relationships in Rails 4 presence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms, polymorphic-associations

I can't seem to successfully create new resources from a nested form that has polymorphic associations.

It seems the problem lies in validations with polymorphic 'belongs_to' relationships. For example:

```
class DealerUser < User
  belongs_to :dealer, polymorphic: true, foreign_key: :loginable_id, foreign_type: :loginable_type
  validates :dealer, presence: true
end
```

I am attempting to create a new resource called Dealer.

```
class Dealer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dealer_locations, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :dealer_user, as: :loginable, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :dealer_locations, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for  :dealer_user, allow_destroy: true

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates_associated :dealer_locations
end
```

My form code:

```
<%= form_for(@dealer) do |d| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: d.object %>
  <br>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= d.label :name %>
      <%= d.text_field :name, class:"form-input-field" %>
    </div>

      <h4>Login Credentials</h4><br>
      <%= d.fields_for :dealer_user do |du| %>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= du.label :email %>
            <%= du.text_field :email, class:"form-input-field" %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= du.label :password %>
            <%= du.password_field :password, class:"form-input-field" %>
          </div>
      <% end %>
    <%= d.submit class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
class DealersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @dealer = Dealer.new
    @dealer.build_dealer_user
  end

  def create
    @dealer = Dealer.new(dealer_params)

    puts @dealer.inspect
    puts @dealer.dealer_user.inspect

    if @dealer.save
       redirect_to(@dealer, :notice => 'Dealer was successfully created.')
    end

  def dealer_params
    params.require(:dealer).permit(:name, dealer_user_attributes: [:email, :password, :id])
  end
end
```

When I submit the form, I am getting `DealerUser.dealer can't be blank` error.

```
#<Dealer id: nil, name: "NAME", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
#<DealerUser id: nil, type: "DealerUser", email: "fake@email.com", loginable_id: nil, loginable_type: "Dealer",...
```

It looks like the associations are working, since you can see type fields are set.

Update 3/11/16: params

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", 
"dealer"=>{"name"=>"ZZ WATER", 
"dealer_user_attributes"=>{"email"=>"...", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, 
"dealer_locations_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"phone"=>"...", "contact_email"=>"...", 
"address_attributes"=>{"line_1"=>"line1", "line_2"=>"", "city"=>"city", "country_code"=>"US", "state_code"=>"CA", "zip_code"=>"00000"}}}}, "commit"=>"Create Dealer"}
```

**Is this an order of operations issue? DealerUser needs an ID to pass validation, but the Dealer ID wont get set until it's saved to the DB, which isn't happening since it's not passing validation. Can someone offer me some guidance.**

Also, this is a simplified version of what I'm working on, there are nested locations and addresses too. I'm also only a couple months into using ruby on rails. Thank you.

Comment: Can you insert `puts params` at the start of `def create`, and update your question with that output? That would be helpful.

Comment: Can you temporarily comment out all `validates_associated` in your `class Dealer`? Then, can you add this `puts @dealer.errors.full_messages`? after `if @dealer.save end`? and tell me the output.

Comment: (I can't fix my mistaken comment about due to timeout)
When I comment out `validates :dealer, presence: true' in DealerUser, the error goes away. Which begets the question of validating the presence of a associated objects. Dealer `has_one` DealerUser. And DealerUser `belongs_to` Dealer. What would an appropriate validation look like for the relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a fresh similar project. And I also got the same error. In my attempt to fix this problem, I stumbled upon [inverse_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Setting+Inverses), and it now worked.

Now try

```
class DealerUser < User
  # ..
  belongs_to :dealer, polymorphic: true, foreign_key: :loginable_id, foreign_type: :loginable_type, inverse_of: :dealer_user
  # ..
end

class Dealer < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ..
  has_one :dealer_user, as: :loginable, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :dealer
  # ..
end
```